# Google App Maker How to Allow access to user to your App Instance who don't have Gsuite

Tags: google-app-maker

How do I allow a normal gmail user access to use on the Google App Maker apps I've made. Is this possible ? 
If you have to have a separate gsuite account for each user using the app then how viable is it ?

Anyway any help would be much appreciated.

Many thanks

Samuel

Comment: At this point in time App Maker applications are automatically restricted to users with an email that resides in the same domain as where the application is published in. I.e. application is published in domain.com, all users with email at domain.com can access application unless application security settings prevent this. To my understanding Google may be working on opening up App Maker applications so other users can access them, however there is no timeline indicated.

Comment: Hi Markes, I get that is a bit frustrating since having a whole gsuite account just for the app isn't necessarily sustainable.

Comment: I'm hoping Google will get this accomplished soon as I am too in a situation where I am receiving data from people outside of our domain through a Google Apps Script application that then gets imported into App Maker. This is very frustrating but I suppose necessary right now. After all, we had the Apps Script application before App Maker and just stored data on a local drive. Switching access to anyone through App Maker would certainly improve our business flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I just spent too much time to get the answer.
So [here](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/getting-started/faq#app_sharing) there is google's answer:

> **Can I share my apps with users outside my organization?**
>   No. Only users in your G Suite organization can use your app. For some apps,
>   you can work around this limitation by using Google Forms to collect
>   user input in Google Sheets, then import the data from the sheet.

I don't think that the form "hack" is going to help a lot of people, but it's nice they mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you **do** need a [GSuite business account](https://gsuite.google.com/pricing.html) ($10/month/user) to use an App Maker app.

I hope that Google is not primarily doing that to make money, but to initially have a smaller number of users and apps, and use the smaller user base to shake out issues and later open it up for the general public (ie for the Firebase platform). I don't see why this would be impossible or even difficult, but of course, hope is not a strategy.